# Setting up powerline-fonts in my text console: setfont works but setupcon doesn't

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fonts, console, tty

I'm trying to permanently set my text console font to use powerline fonts on Ubuntu 19.04 and I can't seem to get it to stick. I copied my fonts into the right dir like so:

```
sudo cp -r Terminus/PSF/*.psf.gz /usr/share/consolefonts
```

If I run

```
setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz
```

on the console, it correctly sets the font. However, if I add:

```
FONT="ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz"
```

to both (or either) `/etc/vconsole.conf` and/or `/etc/default/console-setup` it doesn't seem to persist. When I do this and I run

```
sudo setupcon -v
```

It looks like it's running the right commands to set the fonts, but when it's done it's not working as expected. Here's the output from that command:

```
Configuring /dev/tty1 /dev/tty2 /dev/tty3 /dev/tty4 /dev/tty5 /dev/tty6
The charmap is UTF-8
BackSpace is ^?
executing setfont -C /dev/tty1 /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz.
setfont: graphics console /dev/tty1 skipped
executing setfont -C /dev/tty2 /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz.
setfont: graphics console /dev/tty2 skipped
executing setfont -C /dev/tty3 /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz.
Read 512-char 8x16 font from file /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz
Read 512-char 8x16 font from file /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz
Loading 1024-char 8x16 font
Loading Unicode mapping table...
executing setfont -C /dev/tty4 /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz.
Read 512-char 8x16 font from file /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz
Read 512-char 8x16 font from file /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz
Loading 1024-char 8x16 font
Loading Unicode mapping table...
executing setfont -C /dev/tty5 /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz.
Read 512-char 8x16 font from file /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz
Read 512-char 8x16 font from file /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz
Loading 1024-char 8x16 font
Loading Unicode mapping table...
executing setfont -C /dev/tty6 /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz.
Read 512-char 8x16 font from file /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz
Read 512-char 8x16 font from file /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz
Loading 1024-char 8x16 font
Loading Unicode mapping table...
on /dev/tty1  executing printf.
on /dev/tty2  executing printf.
on /dev/tty3  executing printf.
on /dev/tty4  executing printf.
on /dev/tty5  executing printf.
on /dev/tty6  executing printf.
on /dev/tty1  executing kbd_mode -u.
on /dev/tty2  executing kbd_mode -u.
on /dev/tty3  executing kbd_mode -u.
on /dev/tty4  executing kbd_mode -u.
on /dev/tty5  executing kbd_mode -u.
on /dev/tty6  executing kbd_mode -u.
executing loadkeys /run/tmpkbd.3ChpoS.
```

It seems like everything ran as expected, so I don't understand why it's not working. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Maybe it requires a logout / login?

Comment: Tried that, still nothing :(. However, when I use `setfont` it will stay correctly set with a logout/login too

Answer (score 0):

Did you remove / comment out the following lines?

```
CODESET="Lat15"
FONTFACE="TerminusBold"
FONTSIZE="8x16"
```

This was missing in my setup at first.

My /etc/default/console-setup now looks like this and it works as expected (powerline font in tty1-tty6).

```
ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-6]"
CHARMAP="UTF-8"
FONT="ter-powerline-v18n.psf.gz"
VIDEOMODE=
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Ubuntu 18.04.

## Fix:

1. Rename your fontfiles in `/usr/share/consolefonts` to a name resembling `<CODESET>-<FONTFACE><FONTSIZE>.psf.gz`, where `CODESET`, `FONTFACE` and `FONTSIZE` match appropriate lines in `/etc/default/console-setup`
2. Edit appropriate lines in `/etc/default/console-setup` so they match the filenames.

## Example:

I renamed my fontfile from `ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz` to `Uni2-Terminess16n.psf.gz`. My `console-setup` contains the following lines:

```
CODESET="Uni2"
FONTFACE="Terminess"
FONTSIZE="16n"
```

## Explanation:

As you can see in the output of `sudo setupcon -v` it invokes `setfont` with the following arguments: `-C /dev/tty6 /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz /etc/console-setup/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz`. Font filename appears two times, and that seems to be the problem. If multiple font filenames are placed as values of `FONT` in `/etc/default/console-setup`, each of them will be duplicated by `setupcon` when invoking `setfont`. It doesn't seem it should work this way, but im not sure if it is a bug.

According to `man setfont`, if multiple fontfiles are passed as arguments to `setfont`, it will attempt to combine them into a single font and load it. Judging by the output of `showconsolefont`, passing the same filename twice results in a font with 256 glyphs instead of the full 512 being loaded.

Solution exploits the way `setupcon` processes the `FONTFACE` variable to find and load a fontfile corresponding to a given fontface. Finding our font this way works around `FONT` elements being duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem at Ubuntu 22.04.4., but resolved as below. In short, I remade a psf file.

1. Download psf file from https://github.com/powerline/fonts/blob/master/Terminus/PSF/ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz . This file itself causes the same problem.
2. Unzip file:

   ```
   gzip -d ter-powerline-v16n.psf.gz
   ```
3. Make a bdf file by using psf2bdf tool: https://gist.github.com/froh/1bb10ce5752f37eefe1b

   ```
   perl psf2bdf.pl ter-powerline-v16n.psf | sudo tee ter-powerline-v16n.bdf
   ```
4. Adjust this bdf file: Add these lines before ENDPROPERTIES line:

   ```
   FONT_ASCENT 16
   FONT_DESCENT 0
   AVERAGE_WIDTH 80
   ```
5. Remake a psf file by using `bdf2psf` that is installed by `apt`.

   ```
   bdf2psf --fb ter-powerline-v16n.bdf /usr/share/bdf2psf/standard.equivalents /usr/share/bdf2psf/ascii.set 256 ter-powerline-v16n-new.psf
   ```

   (I'm not sure that these parameters are correct)
6. Set this new psf file in `/etc/default/console-setup` as

   ```
   FONT="ter-powerline-v16n-new.psf"
   ```

   OR gzip compressed

   ```
   FONT="ter-powerline-v16n-new.psf.gz"
   ```
7. Execute `setupcon` or `service console-setup restart`, otherwise `reboot`. The font is still retained. Certainly `setfont` is effective too.

I guess that the new psf file has something differences from the first one, but I cannot grasp because they are binary files.